# R Plotly Returns Blank Sunburst Chart

Tags: r, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to create a sunburst chart using `plotly`, but it returns a blank chart. My dataset contains currency information which is similar to below (except more rows):

```
df <- data.frame(
MainGroup = c("A", "A","A"),
Currency = c("USD","EUR","GBP"),
Percent = c(90,5,5),
Category = c("USD","Other","Other"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The `Category` is based on the `Percent` column: anything less than 10 will be categorized as "Other". I tried `plot_ly(df, labels = ~Currency, parents = ~Category, values = ~Percent, type = 'sunburst')`, but it returned a blank chart. I'd like to create a chart like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
        MainGroup = c("A", "A","A"),
        Currency = c("USDollars","EUR","GBP"),
        Percent = c(90,5,5),
        Category = c("USD","Other","Other"),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    

plot_ly(labels = c(" ", "USD","Other",df$Currency), parents = c(""," "," ",df$Category), values = c(100,90,10,df$Percent), type = 'sunburst',
    branchvalues='total')
```

Multiple problems here (I have to say these sunburst plots are tricky):

- You have to provide for each element the parents, in your example  `Other`has no parent
- You have two different items called `USD`, this is a problem to specify parents, I changed one to `USDollars`
- To get whole circles, you have to put `branchvalues='total'`

[image]

Comment: the first problem you pointed out is exactly the issue I'm facing. In my full dataset, I have lots more currencies and they are changing every month. Is it possible to eliminate the manual process of entering labels and parents in 'plotly'?If not, is there another package I can use?